# PC Powering off during boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, ssd, poweroff

My PC is performing strangely the past 2 days. If my pc starts up with a normal boot, restart etc. everything is fine.

On the other hand if it is "fast-booting", the windows boot logo is displayed for a couple of seconds and then it powers off completely. After that it performs a normal boot. Which takes surprisingly long time for a system with an ssd. (Previous installation of windows 8.1 lead to 5 seconds boot time, now it is about 20).

Fast boot is enabled both in UEFI and Windows (10). Power plan favors performance. If pc specs are required I will edit my question.

I cannot trace the problem to its source.

Answer (score 0):

In shutdown before fast startup, Windows stores the OS state on the drive, similar to hibernation (though without running application state) in   [*hiberfil.sys*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj835779%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If that file were to be corrupted, it could prevent a subsequent fast boot.

Try temporarily disabling hibernation, either from the power options menu, or [by opening an elevated-rights CMD dialog and entering](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/920730):

> powercfg.exe /hibernate off

This should delete *hiberfil.sys*, or allow it to be manually deleted.

Then re-enable hibernation with

> powercfg.exe /hibernate on

Hopefully, that will fix the issue.

Comment: That did not resolve the issue. It is still powering off during fast-boot. I noticed that when it fails to startup and then tries to normal boot, I get a QCode 66 which indicates that this is a memory problem. However I tried reseating, changing slots etc. and other than the fast startup I have no other issues with my RAM.